Openssl ssl_connect() fails with unexpected eof while reading
I have a class using Openssl. It works 99.99% of the time but occasionally I keep getting an error inside SSL_connect():

errno details: 40D6FFD6FF7F0000:error:0A000126:SSL
routines:ssl3_read_n:unexpected eof while
reading:../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:317

I think it's line 466 here:

My function calling SSL_connect() is protected by a static mutex and on the latest occurence, no other threads were calling Openssl.
This code generated the error message:
static inline std::string getOpenSSLError()
{
    BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
    ERR_print_errors(bio);
    char *buf;
    size_t len = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &buf);
    std::string ret(buf, len);
    BIO_free(bio);
    return ret;
}

Can anyone help what I can check/look for?
